# Get print composer to acknowledge the "Lock Layers" option when using the "Render Layers as a Group" option

Tags: qgis, print-composer, group-layer

I have shapefiles and rasters loaded into a QGIS workspace (3.30, but this issue doesn't seem to be version specific from my experience). I've grouped some of the vector layers and checked the "Render Layers as a Group" option, with opacity set to 33%. I have created a print layout with a single map element and a few text boxes. I tick the “Lock layers” option once I have the map set up how I want it before I move onto the next maps.

If I return to a map to make some updates and untick the lock layers option, then tick it again once I’ve made my changes, it appears that any groups being rendered as a layer now ignore the lock layers option and turn on/off based on whether they’re displaying in the main QGIS window – as if the lock layers option is unticked. All other layers work fine.

I’ve tried:

- Using a new workspace
- Creating a new print layout rather than use a template
- Using data in multiple formats (e.g. shp, gdb, gpkg)
- Multiple user accounts/PCs
- QGIS 3.28 and 3.30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been resolved in QGIS 3.32
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/53379